# checking object for blank values and show errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, validation

I am trying to figure out how I can check if any values in the object are blank, and then show the corresponding error.

The form inputs look like this:

```
<form role="form" action="home.php" class="addLaneForm" id="addLaneForm" name="addLaneForm">
  <label for="addlanepartnercode">Partner Code</label><span id="addlanepartnercodeError" class="text-danger laneError" style="display:none;"> * </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control validation" id="addlanepartnercode" placeholder="Enter Partner Code" />

  <label for="addlanepartnername">Partner Name</label><span id="addlanepartnernameError" class="text-danger laneError" style="display:none;"> *  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control validation" id="addlanepartnername" placeholder="Enter Partner Name" />

  <label for="addlaneipicy">IPI/CY</label><span id="addlaneipicyError" class="text-danger laneError" style="display:none;"> * </span>
  <select class="form-control validation" id="addlaneipicy">
     <option></option>
     <option value="YES">YES</option>
     <option value="NO">NO</option>
   </select>

   // few more inputs and selects

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat addLaneSubmit" id="addLaneSubmit" name="addLaneSubmit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Here is the onClick event:

```
$('#addLaneSubmit').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  let partnerCode = $('#addlanepartnercode').val();
  let partnerName = $('#addlanepartnername').val();
  let ipiCy = $('#addlaneipicy').val();

  let addlane = new ProcessLane();

  let addlanecriteria = {
    partnerCode: partnerCode,
    partnerName: partnerName,
    ipiCy: ipiCy
  }

  // how I typically would check the values below:

  if(addlanecriteria.partnerCode == ""){
    $('#addlanepartnercodeError').show();
    return false;
  }
  if(addlanecriteria.partnerName == ""){
    $('#addlanepartnernameError').show();
    return false;
  }
  else{
    addlane.addLaneProcessing(addlanecriteria);
  }
});
```

The way I typically check the values is redundant and time consuming.

I did add a class to the inputs called 'laneError'.  I was trying to use that to display the errors by calling a function, as follows:

```
function showAllErrors(){
  if($(".addLaneForm .validation") == ""){
    $('.laneError').show();
  }
}
```

For one, I wasn't sure where I could put the function call.

But when I was able to call the function, I can only get the first error to show, which is "addlanepartnercodeError".

There has to be a simpler way to check the values in the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can just have a reusable function like below:

```
showErrorMsg(elemId) {
  if($.trim($('#' + elemid).val()) === '') {
    $('#' + elemId + 'Error').show()
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

So your code would just be:-

```
$('#addLaneSubmit').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let Error = false,
  addlane = new ProcessLane();

  $('form')
    .find("input[id^='add']")
    .each((i , e){
      if(!Error) {
        Error = showErrorMsg($(e).attr('id')) 
      }
   })

   if(!Error) {
     // Your form has no errors , do your thing here
     addlane.addLaneProcessing(addlanecriteria);
   }
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an error pointing at this part: '#add']'

Comment: @JohnBeasley had typed it offhand , just test it out now , basically , it should be `"input[id^='add']"` , double quotes and no `#` and the each loop should have `(i , e)` passed

Comment: Error: elemid is not defined

Comment: @JohnBeasley that should't be the case really , can you post the JS and demo html code your using here https://jsfiddle.net/ , save and then paste the generated link below

Comment: @JohnBeasley my bad there should be a `#` before elemid

Comment: Where am I putting the # before elemid?